# Rally REST API with perl: cannot access the Rally server

Tags: perl, rest, rally

I am using perl version 5.16 with the REST modules on a Windows 7 PC.
I cannot get a server response from the Rally server.
Here my code (now with proxy authentication):

```
use REST::Client;   # A simple client for interacting with RESTful http/https resources
use Data::Dumper;   # 
use MIME::Base64;   # Encoding and decoding of base64 strings

my $RallyUser = "myRallyUsername";
my $RallyPassword = "myRallyPassword";
my $rally_server_adress = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
my $wsapi_endpoint = "/slm/webservice/v2.0/";

my $client = REST::Client->new();
$client->addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
$client->addHeader("Authorization", "Basic".encode_base64($RallyUser.":".$RallyPassword));
$client->getUseragent()->proxy(['http', 'https', 'ftp'], 'http://user:password@www-proxy.example:8080');

$client->setHost($rally_server_adress);

$client->GET($wsapi_endpoint."/hierarchicalrequirement?query=( FormattedID = US302)&fetch=TaskRemainingTotal");

print Dumper (\$client->responseCode());
print Dumper (\$client->responseContent());
```

The dumper output is as follows:

```
$VAR1 = \'404';
$VAR1 = \'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /slm/webservice/v2.0//hierarchicalrequirement was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>...</address>
</body></html>
';
```

It seems that the error message is from the proxy server. Or is this an error from the Rally server, which is passed through the proxy?

Using Chrome with a REST plugin I get a valid response from the Rally server.

Thanks in advance,
Erwin

Comment: Try https url within web browser from the same machine.